# $g \circ f$ trivial implies that $Im f \subseteq ker g$

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $f:X_1 \rightarrow  X_2$ and $g:X_2 \rightarrow  X_3$ are homomorphisms. 
If $g \circ f =0$ does it imply that $Im f \subseteq  ker g$? and how to show that? do you have an example?
thanks :)

Comment: Do you know the definitions of $\text{ker}$ and $\text{im}$?

Comment: @Danial Note that this is a necessary and sufficient condition so you can prove also that $Im f\subset Ker g$ implies $g\circ f$ is trivial.

Answer (score 3):

Take an element $y\in Im f$. Then $y$ is of the form $y=f(x)$, for some $x\in X_1$. Now apply $g$ to $y$. You get $g(y)=g(f(x))=(g\circ f)(x)$, which is zero by assumption. As an example, take $f$ arbitrary and $g(y)=0$ for every $y\in X_2$.

Comment: is it necessary that f is onto in this case?

Comment: @Danial It isn't necessary. That wasn't used anywhere.

Comment: thank you very much.. and i like the "+1" :D

Comment: @Danial no, it's not, because $g$ sends everything to zero in any case. Conversely, if you assume that $f$ is onto, then $Im f=X_2=Ker(g)$, so that $g$ must be the constant morphism sending everything to zero

Comment: @GitGud And also because the answer is correct.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Of course, but usually I refrain from $+1$ing an answer which has been given before. Not in this case though.

Answer (score 2):

If $f(x) \in \operatorname{im}f$ was not in $\ker g$, then $g(f(x)) \neq 0$

Answer (score 2):

Things in $Im(f)$ look like $f(x)$, any $y$ such that $g(y)=0$ is in the kernel of $g$,  and $g(f(x))=0$. You have everything you need.

Comment: @Danial $f$ is onto $Im(f)$ by definition. It is irrelevant if $f$ is not onto the entire $X_2$.